# Bundle.js file isn't getting generated by webpack for production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm unable to generate the bundle.js file.

> This is my webpack.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
  path: __dirname,
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
  loaders: [{
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
    }
  }]
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

> This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "redux-react",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
  "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
  "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
  "jquery": "^2.2.1",
  "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
  "mocha": "^2.4.5",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
  "lodash": "^3.10.1",
  "react": "^0.14.3",
  "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
  "react-redux": "4.3.0",
  "react-router": "^2.0.1",
  "redux": "^3.0.4"
} 
}
```

The main aim is to build a production-ready app hence how do I configure my webpack to generate the bundle.js file. Also is it necessary to have seperate webpack.config for dev and production server?

Answer (score 1):

webpack-dev-server is for development purpose. This will not put your bundle.js in your work directory, it will compile your files in-memory.
I can see from your package scripts that you are running a webpack-dev-server to build the code